# Import data quickbook to openerp for version 7

Tags: odoo

Openerp version 7 is any module available for import data from Quickbooks into OpenERP ?... and depends module "import_base".

currenltly old Version "import_quickbooks", "import_base" available but it not working in version 7.

Answer (score 0):

there is a module called `base_import` in openerp 7. You can try it.

Comment: Where is branch, so I can download code ? Other depends modules too ?

Comment: base_import is a default openerp module

Comment: Hi guys,

I am looking for a solution where I will be able to export data to quickbooks from openerp on a daily basis. If any of you find something suitable for this requirement, please do comment.

Thanks,

Comment: for that you need to create some script